# How can I change the color of iTerm2 on IPython shell?

Tags: terminal, ipython, iterm2

I want to change the color of my IPython shell on iTerm2, but athough I can change the color of the iTerm2, I could not change the content of the IPython shell.

The iTerm2 color can be changed from *Preferences | Profiles | Window*, but whatever color scheme I choose does not change the color of the IPython shell, for example `import` or `try` keyword.

So I think it is decided in other places. How can I change the color of the IPython shell?

Comment: There is a magic, `%colors`, that possibly does what you want

Comment: @gboffi Does this enable only three colors, Linux, NoColor, and LightBG, right? All of them are pretty bad in my opinion... (e.g. `import` is near visible).

Comment: Right.   Two color schemes and no color, that's all, sorry.  I use a light bg and IPython insisted in using very bright colors, until I found the `%colors LightBg` command that improved _very much_ my situation, I hoped it could be the same for you...

Comment: @gboffi I found that there are more options available for `TerminalInteractiveShell`. Check my answer if you have the interest.

Comment: I have the interest... Thank you, ciao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it through [`TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/details.html#terminal-colors). I set the following to my `ipython_config.py`:

```
c.InteractiveShell.colors = "Linux"
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style = "vim"
```

The available colors for `TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style` can be obtained with the following code:

```
import pygments
list(pygments.styles.get_all_styles())
```